# GWT data grid isn't presented

Tags: java, gwt, datagrid

I'm trying to switch from CellTable to DataGrid. The actual change was very easy (APIs are the quite the same) - but I cannot get the grid to be visible without setting explicitly its width and height. In the CellTable it was enough to set width and height to 100% - and that is the behavior I want.

In my view I have two sections in HotrizontalPanel: one shows some tabs (buttons) and the other shows the grid. Each time a tab is clicked, the grid area is cleared and a new grid is created.

The view looks like this:

```
<ui:style>
    .expanded {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }

    .simpleContainer {
        border-top: 5px solid #484848;
        border-bottom: 5px solid #484848;
    }
</ui:style>

<c:SimpleContainer addStyleNames="{style.simpleContainer} SimpleContainer">
    <g:HorizontalPanel>
        <g:HorizontalPanel ui:field="headersContainer"/>
        <g:FlowPanel ui:field="tablePanel" styleName="{style.expanded}"/>
    </g:HorizontalPanel>
</c:SimpleContainer>
```

And this is the snap of HTML from the running application:

```
<div class="GKQJTVMDCNC-com-mycode-management-client-ui-panels-PropertiesPaneView_PropertiesPaneUiBinderImpl_GenCss_style-simpleContainer SimpleContainer" id="x-widget-21" style="width: 1730px; height: 126px; ">
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td align="left" style="vertical-align: top; ">....</td>
            <td align="left" style="vertical-align: top; ">
                <div class="GKQJTVMDBNC-com-mycode-management-client-ui-panels-PropertiesPaneView_PropertiesPaneUiBinderImpl_GenCss_style-expanded">
                    <div style="position: relative; overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: hidden; " __gwtcellbasedwidgetimpldispatchingfocus="true" __gwtcellbasedwidgetimpldispatchingblur="true">
                        ....
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The upper div has the right width and height, but somehow the DataGrid div has 1px height and 0px width (at list according to the chrome developer tool)

```
<div class="GKQJTVMDBNC-com-mycode-management-client-ui-panels-PropertiesPaneView_PropertiesPaneUiBinderImpl_GenCss_style-expanded">
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, `CellTable` did work with 100% height and width.
However the ''DataGrid'' doesn't. 
You need to set an explicit width/height.
Alternatively you can put your ''DataGrid'' in a ''LayoutPanel'' that implements the [ProvidesResize](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/ProvidesResize.html) interface (i.e. [SimpleLayoutPanel](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/SimpleLayoutPanel.html)).
The benefit of using a LayoutPanel is that the Datagrid is automatically resized when you resize your browser window.

Comment: Thanks! I saw that note about SimpleLayoutPanel somewhere, tried it, but no luck :(  I tried again now, and it adds another <div> wrapping the DataGrid, but still nothing is visible. This is the added div:
<div style="position: absolute; overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: hidden; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%; ">

Comment: Did you add the ``SimpleLayoutPanel`` to a ``RootLayoutPanel`` ?

Comment: No, I tried to put this SimpleLayoutPanel in the table (created by the HorizontalPanel). Look at the UIBinder above, the 'tabelPanel' is now SimpleLayoutPanel and not FlowPanel

Comment: Can you post your ''onModuleLoad'' code. 
You have to make sure that you use ``RootLayoutPanel`` instead of the normal ``RootPanel`` if you use ``LayoutPanels``. 
Also try to avoid mixing ''LayoutPanels'' with table based panels like  HorizontalPanel.

Comment: I'm using GWTP so i'm not actually putting the content myself on the root. But I just noticed the GWTP supports selecting between the RootPanel and the RootLayoutPanel. I changed my code to use the RootLayoutPanel but it didn't help.
BTW - if it helps to understand - using GWTP RootLayoutPanel option adds content in the following way: RootPanel.get().add(RootLayoutPanel.get()), and adds my content to the RootLayoutPanel.
The above html snippet is of-course a small part from quite complex layout, something else I should look at?

Answer (score 1):

Putting the DataGrid inside SimpleLayoutPanel (and putting everything on the RootLayoutPanel) does help, thanks!.

**But** it works only in this simple case - in my layout it won't help. It seems that because the table is inside HorizontalPanel it won't get appropriate size. Breaking the HorizontalPanel to two divs with appropriate CSS to make them horizontal, won't help either.

Finally, I managed to fix that through settings explicitly width and height to the DataGrid, (taking values from the hosting parent widget). I don't like this solution, but that's the best I could come up with after long trial-and-error. 
I cannot find good examples of using the DataGrid not in a 'static' manner: GWT showcase presents only the obvious case - the grid is initialized with data **before** it is presented. This is not the common case at all...

Comment: Can you show the code to take the values from the hosting parent? Thanks!